# CUDA error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'void'

Tags: c++, cuda

I am new to CUDA programing. To practice, I am trying to run a very simple program that adds elements in two arrays together and then stores the result in a new array. For organization purposes, I am trying to do this by separating the code into multiple files. THANK YOU IN ADVANCED!

I keep getting this error when I try to compile it:
"hello.cpp:6: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘void’"

Here is the code:
**hello.cpp**

```
#include <simple.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 100

__global__ void add(int *a, int *b, int *c)
{

  int tID = blockIdx.x;
  if (tID < N)
    {
      adding(a, b, c, tID);
    }
}

int main()
{
  int a[N], b[N], c[N];
  int *dev_a, *dev_b, *dev_c;
  cudaMalloc((void **) &dev_a, N*sizeof(int));
  cudaMalloc((void **) &dev_b, N*sizeof(int));
  cudaMalloc((void **) &dev_c, N*sizeof(int));
  // Fill Arrays
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
      a[i] = i,
    b[i] = 1;
    }
  cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(dev_b, b, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  add<<<N,1>>>(dev_a, dev_b, dev_c);
  cudaMemcpy(c, dev_c, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
      printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a[i], b[i], c[i]);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

**simple.cpp**

```
#include <simple.h>

__device__ void adding(int *a, int *b, int *c, int tID)
{
       c[tID] = a[tID] + b[tID];  
}
```

**simple.h**

```
#ifndef __simple_h__
#define __simple_h__

 __device__ void adding(int *a, int *b, int *c, int tID);
#endif
```

**Makefile**

```
objects = hello.o simple.o

all: $(objects)
    /usr/local/cuda-7.0/bin/nvcc -arch=sm_20 $(objects) -o app

%.o: %.cpp %.cu
    /usr/local/cuda-7.0/bin/nvcc -x cu -arch=sm_20 -I. -dc $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f *.o app
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your project on my computer, `make` seems to use its [implicit variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html) when compiling *.cpp files which results in using `g++` instead of using `nvcc` as you specified.

To change this behavior, you have to set the variables `CXX` and `CXXFLAGS`. The following `Makefile` worked for me:

```
objects = hello.o simple.o

CXX = /usr/local/cuda-7.0/bin/nvcc
CXXFLAGS = -x cu -arch=sm_20 -I. -dc

all: $(objects)
    $(CXX) $(objects) -o app

%.o: %.cpp %.cu
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because of the declarations of `__global__` on the host side cpp file. Try putting all the cuda code in a .cu file.

Comment: Is there a way that I could put just the CUDA kernel, where the __gobal__ function is declared in its own .cu file and leave everything else where it is?